# How to add a constant column in a Spark DataFrame?

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to add a column in a `DataFrame` with some arbitrary value (that is the same for each row). I get an error when I use `withColumn` as follows:

```
dt.withColumn('new_column', 10).head(5)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-a6d0257ca2be> in <module>()
      1 dt = (messages
      2     .select(messages.fromuserid, messages.messagetype, floor(messages.datetime/(1000*60*5)).alias("dt")))
----> 3 dt.withColumn('new_column', 10).head(5)

/Users/evanzamir/spark-1.4.1/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.pyc in withColumn(self, colName, col)
   1166         [Row(age=2, name=u'Alice', age2=4), Row(age=5, name=u'Bob', age2=7)]
   1167         """
-> 1168         return self.select('*', col.alias(colName))
   1169 
   1170     @ignore_unicode_prefix

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'alias'
```

It seems that I can trick the function into working as I want by adding and subtracting one of the other columns (so they add to zero) and then adding the number I want (10 in this case):

```
dt.withColumn('new_column', dt.messagetype - dt.messagetype + 10).head(5)
```

```
[Row(fromuserid=425, messagetype=1, dt=4809600.0, new_column=10),
 Row(fromuserid=47019141, messagetype=1, dt=4809600.0, new_column=10),
 Row(fromuserid=49746356, messagetype=1, dt=4809600.0, new_column=10),
 Row(fromuserid=93506471, messagetype=1, dt=4809600.0, new_column=10),
 Row(fromuserid=80488242, messagetype=1, dt=4809600.0, new_column=10)]
```

This is supremely hacky, right? I assume there is a more legit way to do this?

Answer (score 314, accepted):

**Spark 2.2+**

Spark 2.2 introduces `typedLit` to support  `Seq`, `Map`, and `Tuples` ([SPARK-19254](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19254)) and following calls should be supported (Scala):

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.typedLit

df.withColumn("some_array", typedLit(Seq(1, 2, 3)))
df.withColumn("some_struct", typedLit(("foo", 1, 0.3)))
df.withColumn("some_map", typedLit(Map("key1" -> 1, "key2" -> 2)))
```

**Spark 1.3+** (`lit`), **1.4+** (`array`, `struct`), **2.0+** (`map`):

The second argument for `DataFrame.withColumn` should be a `Column` so you have to use a literal:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit

df.withColumn('new_column', lit(10))
```

If you need complex columns you can build these using blocks like `array`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import array, create_map, struct

df.withColumn("some_array", array(lit(1), lit(2), lit(3)))
df.withColumn("some_struct", struct(lit("foo"), lit(1), lit(.3)))
df.withColumn("some_map", create_map(lit("key1"), lit(1), lit("key2"), lit(2)))
```

Exactly the same methods can be used in Scala.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{array, lit, map, struct}

df.withColumn("new_column", lit(10))
df.withColumn("map", map(lit("key1"), lit(1), lit("key2"), lit(2)))
```

To provide names for `structs` use either `alias` on each field:

```
df.withColumn(
    "some_struct",
    struct(lit("foo").alias("x"), lit(1).alias("y"), lit(0.3).alias("z"))
 )
```

or `cast` on the whole object

```
df.withColumn(
    "some_struct", 
    struct(lit("foo"), lit(1), lit(0.3)).cast("struct<x: string, y: integer, z: double>")
 )
```

It is also possible, although slower, to use an UDF.

**Note**:

The same constructs can be used to pass constant arguments to UDFs or SQL functions.

Comment: For others using this to implement... the withColumn method returns a new DataFrame by adding a column or replacing the existing column that has the same name, so you'll need to reassign the results to df or assign to a new variable. For example, `df = df.withColumn('new_column', lit(10))'

Comment: with every iteration , can we change the values inside the column? i have already tried this  ```for i in range(len(item)) : df.withColumn('new_column', lit({}).format(i)) ``` but this doesn't work

Comment: @zero323 are you sure there is a function called "map" to add a literal map to code.

Comment: @BdEngineer it is `map` in Scala and `create_map` in Pyspark

Answer (score 53):

In spark 2.2 there are two ways to add constant value in a column in DataFrame:

1) Using `lit`

2) Using `typedLit`.

The difference between the two is that `typedLit` can also handle parameterized scala types e.g. List, Seq, and Map

**Sample DataFrame:**

```
val df = spark.createDataFrame(Seq((0,"a"),(1,"b"),(2,"c"))).toDF("id", "col1")

+---+----+
| id|col1|
+---+----+
|  0|   a|
|  1|   b|
+---+----+
```

**1) Using `lit`:** Adding constant string value in new column named newcol:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit
val newdf = df.withColumn("newcol",lit("myval"))
```

Result:

```
+---+----+------+
| id|col1|newcol|
+---+----+------+
|  0|   a| myval|
|  1|   b| myval|
+---+----+------+
```

**2) Using `typedLit`:**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.typedLit
df.withColumn("newcol", typedLit(("sample", 10, .044)))
```

Result:

```
+---+----+-----------------+
| id|col1|           newcol|
+---+----+-----------------+
|  0|   a|[sample,10,0.044]|
|  1|   b|[sample,10,0.044]|
|  2|   c|[sample,10,0.044]|
+---+----+-----------------+
```

Comment: Could you share the complete version along with import statement

Comment: spark version 2.2.1. import statement is from pyspark.sql.functions import typedLit. Also tried the one shared by you above.

Answer (score 5):

As the other answers have described, `lit` and `typedLit` are how to add constant columns to DataFrames.  `lit` is an important Spark function that you will use frequently, but not for adding constant columns to DataFrames.

You'll commonly be using `lit` to create `org.apache.spark.sql.Column` objects because that's the column type required by most of the `org.apache.spark.sql.functions`.

Suppose you have a DataFrame with a `some_date` DateType column and would like to add a column with the days between December 31, 2020 and `some_date`.

Here's your DataFrame:

```
+----------+
| some_date|
+----------+
|2020-09-23|
|2020-01-05|
|2020-04-12|
+----------+
```

Here's how to calculate the days till the year end:

```scala
val diff = datediff(lit(Date.valueOf("2020-12-31")), col("some_date"))
df
  .withColumn("days_till_yearend", diff)
  .show()
```

```
+----------+-----------------+
| some_date|days_till_yearend|
+----------+-----------------+
|2020-09-23|               99|
|2020-01-05|              361|
|2020-04-12|              263|
+----------+-----------------+
```

You could also use `lit` to create a `year_end` column and compute the `days_till_yearend` like so:

```scala
import java.sql.Date

df
  .withColumn("yearend", lit(Date.valueOf("2020-12-31")))
  .withColumn("days_till_yearend", datediff(col("yearend"), col("some_date")))
  .show()
```

```
+----------+----------+-----------------+
| some_date|   yearend|days_till_yearend|
+----------+----------+-----------------+
|2020-09-23|2020-12-31|               99|
|2020-01-05|2020-12-31|              361|
|2020-04-12|2020-12-31|              263|
+----------+----------+-----------------+
```

Most of the time, you don't need to use `lit` to append a constant column to a DataFrame.  You just need to use `lit` to convert a Scala type to a `org.apache.spark.sql.Column` object because that's what's required by the function.

See the `datediff` function signature:

[image]

As you can see, `datediff` requires two Column arguments.

Comment: Can we also use `withColumn("days_till_yearend", datediff(lit(Date.valueOf("2020-12-31")), col("some_date")))` negating the need of creating the variable `diff`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add new column in pyspark dataframe with some default value, you can add column by using withColumn and lit() value, below is the sample example for the same.

```
df_new = df_old.withColumn('new_column_name',lit(New_value))
```

Here,

- new_column_name - column you prefer to give
- new_value - value to like to see default for all records.

Thanks