# Add a constant struct column to a Spark DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I want to load a `struct` from a database collection, and attach it as a constant column to every row in a target `DataFrame`.

I can load the column I need as a `DataFrame` with one row, then do a `crossJoin` to paste it onto each row of the target:

```scala
val parentCollectionDF = /* ... load a single row from the database */
val constantCol = broadcast(parentCollectionDF.select("my_column"))
val result = childCollectionDF.crossJoin(constantCol)
```

It works but feels wasteful: the data is constant for each row of the child collection, but the crossJoin copies it to each row.

If I could hardcode the values, I could use something like `childCollection.withColumn("my_column", struct(lit(val1) as "field1", lit(val2) as "field2" /* etc. */))` But I don't know them ahead of time; I need to load the struct from the parent collection.

What I'm looking for is something like:

```scala
childCollection.withColumn("my_column",
  lit(parentCollectionDF.select("my_column").take(1).getStruct(0))
```

... but I can see from [the code for literals](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/literals.scala#L52) that only basic types can be used as an argument to `lit()`. No good to pass a GenericRowWithSchema or a case class here.

Is there a less clumsy way to do this? (Spark 2.1.1, Scala)

*[edit: Not the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32788322/how-to-add-a-constant-column-in-a-spark-dataframe), which explains how to add a struct with literal (hardcoded) constants. My struct needs to be loaded dynamically.]*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a constant column in a Spark DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32788322/how-to-add-a-constant-column-in-a-spark-dataframe)