# Adding a Arraylist value to a new column in Spark Dataframe using Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want add a new column in my existing dataframe. Below is my dataframe -

```
+---+---+-----+
| x1| x2|   x3|
+---+---+-----+
|  1|  a| 23.0|
|  3|  B|-23.0|
+---+---+-----+
```

I am able to add `df = df.withColumn("x4", lit(0))` like this

```
+---+---+-----+---+
| x1| x2|   x3| x4|
+---+---+-----+---+
|  1|  a| 23.0|  0|
|  3|  B|-23.0|  0|
+---+---+-----+---+
```

but I want to add a array list to my df.

Supose this `[0,0,0,0]` is my array to add and after adding my df will look like this -

```
+---+---+-----+---------+
| x1| x2|   x3|       x4|
+---+---+-----+---------+
|  1|  a| 23.0|[0,0,0,0]|
|  3|  B|-23.0|[0,0,0,0]|
+---+---+-----+---------+
```

I tried like this -

```
array_list = [0,0,0,0]
df = df.withColumn("x4", lit(array_list))
```

But it is giving error

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class java.util.ArrayList [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Do anybody know how to do this?

Comment: Perhaps `df.withColumn("some_array", array(lit(0), lit(0), lit(0), lit(0))` ? [src](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32788650/3433323)

Comment: But what if I have to add different value to different row. It is not permanent solution.

Comment: If you need a different value to a different row then you possibly need to use a `udf`.

Comment: Another thought is to use `when` : `df.withColumn('some_array', when((df.some_column==1), array(lit(0), lit(0), lit(0), lit(0)).otherwise(array(lit(1), lit(1), lit(1), lit(1))`

Comment: what does your array depend on ?

Comment: My array is variable and I have to add it to multiple places with different value. This approach is fine for adding either same value or for adding one or two arrays. It will not suit for adding huge data like some 1000 rows.

Answer (score 1):

[Based on your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48379151/adding-a-arraylist-value-to-a-new-column-in-spark-dataframe-using-pyspark#comment83746762_48379151)

> My array is variable and I have to add it to multiple places with different value. This approach is fine for adding either same value or for adding one or two arrays. It will not suit for adding huge data

I believe it an XY-problem. If you want scalable solution (1000 rows in not huge to be honest), then use another dataframe and join. For example if want to connect by `x1`

```
arrays = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]), (3, [0.0, 0.0, 0.0])
], ("x1", "x4"))


df.join(arrays, ["x1"])
```

Add more complex condition depending on the requirements.

To solve you're immediate problem see [How to add a constant column in a Spark DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32788322/how-to-add-a-constant-column-in-a-spark-dataframe) - all elements of `array` should be columns

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit

array(lit(0.0), lit(0.0), lit(0.0))
#  Column<b'array(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)'>
```

Comment: Fine got the point. But one more question what if i want to add different values to each row like this - 
`+---+---+-----+---------+
| x1| x2|   x3|       x4|
+---+---+-----+---------+
|  1|  a| 23.0|[0,1,2,3]|
|  3|  B|-23.0|[4,5,0,7]|
|  4|  C|-23.0|[8,0,1,0]|
+---+---+-----+---------+`