# Apache Spark: Kafka write in custom format

Tags: json, apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql

I'm building a Spark SQL app that consume from a Kafka topic, transform some data, then write back to a separate Kafka topic with a specific JSON object.

I've got most of this working - I can consume, transform, and write back to Kafka - it's the shape of the JSON object being written after the transformation, that I'm struggling with.

Right now I'm able to query/transform what I want and write it:

```
Dataset<Row> reader = myData.getRecordCount();
reader.select(to_json(struct("record_count")).alias("value"))
    .write()
    .format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
    .option("topic", "new_separate_topic")
    .save();
```

This produces a record like this, in the topic:

```
{
  "record_count": 989
}
```

What I need, is for this bit of JSON to be a payload (child) property of a larger JSON object, which we use as a standard consumer object for our microservices.

What I want to write to the topic actually looks like this:

```
{
  "id": "ABC123",
  "timestamp": "2018-11-16 20:40:26.108",
  "user": "DEF456",
  "type": "new_entity",
  "data": {
      "record_count": 989
    }
}
```

Also, the "id", "user", and "type" fields would be populated from the outside - they would come from the original Kafka message that triggers the whole process. Basically, I need to inject some values for the metadata/object I want to write to Kafka, and set the "data" field to the outcome of the Spark SQL query above.

Is this possible? How? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a constant column in a Spark DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32788322/how-to-add-a-constant-column-in-a-spark-dataframe)

Comment: FWIW, reading from Kafka and writing to Kafka is the strong-point of Kafka Streams applications. And you don't need a cluster scheduler like Spark

Comment: Why the downvote!? I realize it's a possible duplicate but I didn't know *what* I was looking for, hence the question.

Comment: @cricket_007 Not sure I follow. I need spark to do data transformations in the middle of the operation. Kafka is just triggering the transformation, which writes a completely new message & payload to a different topic. It's not data moving directly from one topic to another, untouched.

Comment: Kafka Streams is an embeddable Java application specifically designed for such transformations. Refer to the documentation, https://kafka.apache.org/20/documentation/streams/tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add new fields, then you cannot just select only one.

E.g. between `write.format("kafka")` and `.select()`, you need to do [something like `withColumn()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32788322/how-to-add-a-constant-column-in-a-spark-dataframe)

```
Dataset<Row> reader = myData.getRecordCount();
// Keep your DataSet as Columns
reader = reader.select("record_count"))

// Add more data
reader = reader.withColumn(...)

// Then convert structs to JSON and write the output 
reader.select(to_json(...))
    .write()
    .format("kafka")
```

> the "id", "user", and "type" fields would be populated from the outside - they would come from the original Kafka message that triggers the whole process

Then you need to include `select("id", "user", "type")` in your code

Another option is using [Kafka Streams](https://kafka.apache.org/20/documentation/streams/tutorial) rather than being forced into manuipulating DataSets, you can use actual Java classes / JSONObjects

Comment: Thanks very much! This did the trick. I was able to build a new message w/ transformed payload this way. I explained why I needed what I posted in a comment in the OP. Would be interested in your feedback.