# Add mapType column to existing DataFrame

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I have got probably easy and quick question regarding the DataFrames in the Scala in Spark.

I have an existing Spark DataFrame (operate with Scala 2.10.5 and Spark 1.6.3) and would like to add a new column with the ArrayType or MapType, but don't know how to achieve that. But don't know how to deal with that. I would not like to create multiple columns with the 'single' values, but store them in one column. It would shorten my code and make it more changes prone.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.MapType

...

// DataFrame initial creation
val df = ...

// adding new columns
val df_new = df
   .withColumn("new_col1", lit("something_to_add") // add a literal
   .withColumn("new_col2"), MapType("key1" -> "val1", "key2" -> "val2")) // ???
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a constant column in a Spark DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32788322/how-to-add-a-constant-column-in-a-spark-dataframe)

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like

```
val df_new = df
   .withColumn("new_col1", lit("something_to_add") // add a literal
   .withColumn("new_col2"), typedLit[Map[String, String]](Map("key1" -> "val1"), ("key2" -> "val2")))
```

Comment: Unfortunately my Spark 1.6.3 doesn't contain the org.apache.spark.sql.functions.typedLit. Or is the 'typedLit' stored in another package?

Comment: typedLit is from 2.2.0. You could try the following approach. Use a custom defined function on your column(e.g toMap) that return a Map[String, String] and use that like: withColumn("new_col2", toMap(lit("key1->val1")))