# Add date in pyspark data frame

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using Azure databricks Runtime 7.3 LTS
I have pyspark dataframe df. In df I want to add a new column Date_time which will have date value.
So I wrote following comments

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
timestamp='2020-01-03'
df.withColumn('Date_time', timestamp)
```

But I'm getting error message

```
AssertionError: col should be Column
```

How to rectify this error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a constant column in a Spark DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32788322/how-to-add-a-constant-column-in-a-spark-dataframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to the other answer, you might also want to cast the column to timestamp type or date type. Otherwise by default it will be of string type, which is probably not what you want.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

timestamp = '2020-01-03'
df = df.withColumn('Date_time', F.lit(timestamp).cast('timestamp'))

# or, if you want a date type instead,
# df = df.withColumn('Date_time', F.lit(timestamp).cast('date'))
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want your '*Date_time*' column to have literal value then you can use `lit` function for this.

you need to modify your code as follows :

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
timestamp='2020-01-03'
df = df.withColumn('Date_time', F.lit(timestamp))
```