# how to create a new column with Constant Value in pyspark dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I needed to create a new column(FILE_DT)and apply the constant values to all the rows after reading this csv file as a PySpark dataframe.

For example: Sample dataframe

constant values: 2022-10-01

```
NAME   INFO   TITLE   FILE_DT
AAA    222     BBB    2022-10-01
ACC    111     CCB    2022-10-01  
ADD    333     DDC    2022-10-01
ASS    444     NNC    2022-10-01
```

Comment: something like: `df.withColumn("FILE_DT", F.to_date(F.regexp_extract(F.input_file_name(), r"ORDERS_E.*_D(\d+)$", 1), "yyMMdd"))`

Comment: @blackbishop Thanks for your input! Could you pls tell what is F?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a constant column in a Spark DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32788322/how-to-add-a-constant-column-in-a-spark-dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below code, It is working but looking for better logic.

```
from datetime import datetime
object_name = "ORDERS_E220928_D220928.csv"
current_day = datetime.today().strftime("%Y%m%d")
filedate= current_day[0:4] + object_name[18:22]
print(filedate)    #20221011

import datetime
d = datetime.datetime.strptime(filedate, "%Y%m%d")
s = d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
print(s)
df.withColumn("file_dt", lit(s)).show()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df_with_date = df.withColumn("FILE_DT",F.lit("2022-10-01").cast("date"))
```